# Importing Nmap as a library or executing Nmap system commands and storing them in a text file

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, performance, nmap

I'm working on automating a script using Python and cannot figure out which is more efficient:

1. Executing commands and storing them in a text file then inserting the results into MySQL:

> `system('nmap 127.0.0.1')`

2. Importing Python's Nmap library python-nmap and storing the results in MySQL

Anyone have any insight on this? (Of course there are many other factors but the question is referring to the scope above)

Comment: Welcome to SO. In my interpretation, the first option you have listed involves some manual effort for the execution. Since your goal is to automate, your second option seems the better of the two. I will also offer this nugget: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." Focus on getting something working, then focus on making it more efficient. Good luck!

Comment: @gallen Thank you! I've actually already implemented option 1 and it's fully automated. I'm working on making it more efficient and I was wondering if switching to option 2 would do the job.